# Possible raw SQL statement detected. delete from $tableName WHERE sku = $productSku

Tags: database, sql

the code is working well and doing it's job but pipeline on bitbuckets drops an error

```
 Possible raw SQL statement "delete from $tableName WHERE sku = $productSku " detected.
```

my function where this query is located is

```
 private function removeLG()
    {
        $productcollection = $this->collectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer', 'LG')->load();
        $tableName = $this->getTableName('catalog_product_entity');
        foreach ($productcollection as $product) {
               $productSku = $product->getSku();
                $sqls = "delete from $tableName WHERE sku = $productSku ";
                $this->resourceConnection->getConnection()->query($sqls);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

thats how it must be done.

```
    private function removeLG()
    {
        $connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $productcollection = $this->collectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer', 'LG')->load();
        $tableName = $this->getTableName('catalog_product_entity');
        foreach ($productcollection as $product) {
               $productSku = $product->getSku();
               $connection->delete($tableName, "sku = '$productSku'");
        }
    }
```